# Scanf and Dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, matrix, scanf, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
int **elem;
elem = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int**) * numCol);

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < numCol; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &elem[i][j]); //Shouldn't it give a value to the address pointed by 
                                     //a pointer to pointer to int?

        }
```

Why does this code give a segmentation fault error?(Segmentation fault: 11)
And this code works:

```
int **elem;
elem = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int**) * numCol);

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
        elem[i] = (int *)malloc(numCol * sizeof(int));

        // Fill it with values

        for (j = 0; j < numCol; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &elem[i][j]);
        }
```

I'm confused. Besides that segmentation problem, doesn't int ** give a value of 4 ? Why not just use int.

Comment: `int *` and `int **` are very likely to have the same size, but you really ought to write `elem = malloc( numCol * sizeof *elem )` or `elem = malloc( numCol * sizeof(int *))`.  I prefer the former, since it avoids this paticular error nicely.  Note that the cast is unnecessary and potentially problematic.

Comment: Many programming errors have arisen because of the assumption that a pointer has the same size as an integer, and many others because of the assumption that the size is 4.  Perhaps on your machine `sizeof (int) == sizeof (int *) == 4`, but it is certainly not true on all machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code snippet segfaults because you haven’t allocated any memory for the array columns - each `elem[i]` doesn’t point to anything meaningful.

The general pattern for allocating "jagged" arrays like this is as follows:

```
/**
 * Allocate N "rows", which is actually an array of 
 * pointers to T
 */
T **arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * numRows ); // for any type T
if ( arr )
{
  /**
   * For each "row", allocate an array of T
   */
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < numRows; i++ )
  {
    arr[i] = malloc( sizeof *arr[i] * numCols );
    if ( arr[i] )
    {
      for ( size_t j = 0; j < numCols; j++ )
      {
        // initialize arr[i][j]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Pictures may help.

First you start with the `arr` pointer:

```
     T **
     +–––+
arr: |   |
     +–––+
```

Then you allocate an array of pointer to `T` as your “rows” (to keep the picture a reasonable size, we’ll assume two rows and two columns):

```
     T **      T *
     +–––+     +–––+
arr: |   | ––> |   | arr[0]
     +–––+     +–––+
               |   | arr[1]
               +–––+
```

Finally you allocate arrays of `T` for each “row”:

```
     T **      T *               T
     +–––+     +–––+             +–––+
arr: |   | ––> |   | arr[0] –––> |   | arr[0][0]
     +–––+     +–––+             +–––+
               |   | arr[1] –+   |   | arr[0][1]
               +–––+         |   +–––+
                             |
                             |   +–––+
                             +-> |   | arr[1][0]
                                 +–––+
                                 |   | arr[1][1]
                                 +–––+
```

There’s no guarantee that `sizeof (int **)` is the same as `sizeof (int *)` or `sizeof (int)` (on x86_64, pointer sizes are typically 8 bytes).

Note that with this kind of piecemeal allocation, the rows are not going to be contiguous in memory - `arr[1][0]` does not immediately follow `arr[0][1]`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm confused. Besides that segmentation problem, doesn't int ** give a
>   value of 4? Why not just use int.

Not in all machine this is true, so it's correct to use the right type in the sizeof function to avoid error complicated to find out when program is running.

> Why does this code give a segmentation error?(Segmentation fault: 11)
>   And this code works?

the first piece of code has an error in dynamic allocation of memory for the `int** elem` in fact you allocate only a row in the matrix.

In the second code you do the right initialization of the matrix. ***Pay attention*** in the second code your cycle is for i<2. This initialization is correct only if `numCol` is equal to 2.

A better code can be this :

```
int **elem;
elem = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*) * numCol); //a correction in sizeof

        for (i = 0; i < numCol; i++) //cycle on numCol and not on 2
        {
            elem[i] = (int *)malloc(numCol * sizeof(int));

            // Fill it with values

            for (j = 0; j < numCol; j++)
            {
                scanf("%d", &elem[i][j]);
            }
 }
```

Comment: I have tested my int* and int** are the size of 8 and int is 4. They are different.

Comment: Dosen't int** mean we want an allocation of a bidimensional array? Just asking.why use int **?.

Comment: int** is a pointer to pointer to int. And it **can be used** for bidimensional array **but not only for this** . I leave you a useful link: [C-pointer to pointer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_to_pointer.htm)

Comment: Btw, I wrote i<2 because I want to build a table(2 rows).Thank you.